# Output Issue in dev c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

when i run this code  mentioned below, The output console appears for fraction of second and then disappear, but every thing is fine in this code.there is no compile error or warning. i also use get character function but same issue. 
i am using dev-c++ 4.9.9.2 version on win 7, 32 bits. what to do?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{

cout<<"welcm";

return 0;

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the point of the screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cin.get()` before your return statement to avoid the console window from closing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the program to wait before closing.

```
 cout<<"welcm";

 system("pause"); // add this line

 return 0;
```

Comment: BTW, this is specific to Windows. On other operating systems (Linux, MacOSX) you don't have this issue.

Comment: It's a horrible thing to do no matter what OS you're using. It's actually not "specific to Windows": it's specific to the way your IDE invokes `cmd.exe` (i.e. without the `/K` flag) and can be fixed _properly_ without butchering your program.

Comment: For seeing the output of a simple console app it's fine. Hardly "butchering your program"

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy system pause added still issue.